# Trouble using rails commands in pair with guacamole

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, arangodb, guacamole

I'm just trying to use guacamole with rails for a personal project.

I've created my rails app, set my guacamole gem and am now trying to execute :

`rails g model presence public_reference:string solid_reference:string:uniq`

It's the first time I'm trying to use this combination, and I don't realy know where to search and how to debug the error below ...

Also I've tried to generate the model without arguments but I get the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        33: from bin/rails:7:in `<main>'
        32: from bin/rails:7:in `require'
        31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:21:in `perform'
        24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
        22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
        21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require'
        20: from E:/Projets/Rails/exPi/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        17: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/guacamole-0.4.0/lib/guacamole/railtie.rb:31:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/guacamole-0.4.0/lib/guacamole/configuration.rb:176:in `load'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:263:in `load'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:350:in `parse'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:402:in `parse_stream'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:402:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

detail I forgot :

guacamole.yml

```
development:
  protocol: 'http'
  host: 'localhost'
  port: 8529
  username: 'root'
  password: '<%= MY_CONFIG['password'] %>
  database: 'exPi_development'

test:
  protocol: 'http'
  host: 'localhost'
  port: 8529
  username: 'root'
  password: '<%= MY_CONFIG['password'] %>
  database: 'exPi_test'
```

load_my_config.rb

```rb
parent_dir = File.expand_path('..', File.dirname(__FILE__))
credentials_path = File.join(parent_dir, 'credentials.yml')
open_credentials = Psych.load_file(credentials_path)

MY_CONFIG = open_credentials[Rails.env]
```

bin/rails

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'psych'
require 'rails'
require_relative '../config/initializers/load_my_config'
require 'rails/commands'
```

credentials.yml

```
development:
  password: 'password'

test:
  password: 'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find it you'll know how much I'm ashamed of myself ...